# JSF URL rewriting with Prettyfaces Rewrite not working?

Tags: jsf, url-rewriting

I have a test project and i want to rewrite my url with Pretty Rewrite(http://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/)

what i have tried is adding the

> rewrite-servlet-3.0.0.Alpha4.jar

to my netbeans project and i have made a xml file called **pretty-config.xml** in my **WEB-INF** folder.

my **pretty-config.xml** is

```
        <pretty-config xmlns="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces" 
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://ocpsoft.org/schema/rewrite-config-prettyfaces
                          http://ocpsoft.org/xml/ns/prettyfaces/rewrite-config-prettyfaces.xsd">

        <url-mapping id="home">
            <pattern value="/home"/>
            <view-id value="faces/index.xhtml"/>
        </url-mapping>

    </pretty-config>
```

my **web.xml** file is

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
        <context-param>
            <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
            <param-value>Development</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
        <session-config>
            <session-timeout>
                30
            </session-timeout>
        </session-config>
        <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

and made "**ApplicationConfigurationProvider**" in **default package**

```
    import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
    import org.ocpsoft.logging.Logger.Level;
    import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.annotation.RewriteConfiguration;
    import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.Configuration;
    import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.ConfigurationBuilder;
    import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.Direction;
    import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.config.Log;
    import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.HttpConfigurationProvider;
    import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.Path;
    import org.ocpsoft.rewrite.servlet.config.Redirect;

    @RewriteConfiguration
    public class ApplicationConfigurationProvider extends  
    HttpConfigurationProvider {

        @Override
        public Configuration getConfiguration(ServletContext context) {
            return (ConfigurationBuilder.begin()
                    .addRule().perform(Log.message(Level.INFO, "Rewrite is active :D."))

                    .addRule()
                    .when(Direction.isInbound().and(Path.matches("/")))
                    .perform(Redirect.temporary(context.getContextPath() + "/home")));

        }

        @Override
        public int priority() {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

But when I try to access my page **http://localhost:8080/JSFTEst/home**
it gives a 404 error , my server is tomcat **apache-tomcat-7.0.57**

What am I missing here , please help me. Thank You :)

Comment: Change `/home'` to just `home` in pretty-config.xml. .

Comment: thats not working either :(

Comment: The problem is with mapping only, did you change in 'Redirect.temporary' same? I don't work with jsf ever. u need to find a what should mapping while calling a page?

Comment: when i change in **Redirect.temporary**  it outputs the link as **http://localhost:8080/JSFTesthome** which is wrong right?

Comment: i also think that problem is with mapping because the server log shows that **INFO: Rewrite 3.0.0.Alpha4 initialized.**

Comment: and **INFO: Rewrite is active :D.** which is the message i have written in **ApplicationConfigurationProvider** class